# c++ Externally visible const

Tags: c++

I have a function which returns zero on success, or the line number where an error was detected:

```
int func() {
    // stuff
    if (something is wrong) {
        return __LINE__;
    }
    // more stuff
    if (something else is wrong) {
        return __LINE__;
    }
    // all good
    return 0;
}
```

Real callers only check whether the return value is zero or not, often like this:

```
int ret = func();
if (ret != 0) {
    return ret;
}
```

However, during tests I would like to check the actual return value, to verify that a certain fail condition was triggered:

```
int ret = func();
EXPECT_EQ(42, ret);
```

This poses a problem, because when the source file of func() is edited, the lines of the return statements, and hence the values returned, also change. I would like the line number values to be available to the callers of func().

It is possible to "export" line numbers like this:

```
// header
extern const int line_number;

// source
const int line_number = __LINE__;
```

Unfortunately, this only works for line numbers outside a function. I would like something like this:

```
if (something is wrong) {
    const int line_number = __LINE__; return __LINE__;
    // or some other const thing
}
```

that can be read from another translation unit (file).

I tried `static const int line = __LINE__`, but that has two flaws:

- it's not the definition of `line_number` declared in the header.
- it may not be set until execution passes over it.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: If you need to have return codes, returning an `enum` value would be a possible solution instead of line numbers.

Comment: Why not have an `enum` of failure types and return the `enum` value of the failure.  This decouples the error reporting form the file configuration.

Comment: Why on earth would you use line numbers for this? If you explain why exactly you are using them, we might be able to give you a proper answer

Comment: What is the sense in returning the line number where the constant (or whatsoever) is defined? Sound pretty useless to me.

Comment: You could drop the `const` from the global and don't shadow its name with a local variable. Or you could starting using actual error codes with sensible names.

Comment: Every complex problem has simple, easy to understand and wrong solution...

Comment: @MikeMB I'm using line numbers because for the actual (non-test) code, only the success/failure information is interesting, but returning an int gives a bit more information than returning a bool. The value is printed in the logs, which allows developers (me) to divine what was the cause of the error.

Comment: @Olaf Pray tell me, what exactly is not C but C++ in the above code? And no, // comments don't count.

Comment: Sure, comment don't, becasue C also supports line-comments. Just read the standards. But for a starter, because C does not have symbolic constants except for _enum-constants_. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics! You just hit **one** of the differences in both languages.

Comment: And whats stopping you from returning a proper error code, that you e.g. define in a headerfile?

Comment: If the "something that is wrong" is an error from which your program can't recover, then you can use the ASSERT macro, or a macro of your own to use `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to report the problem. If the failure happens in the field, the message will tell you where it happened. If it's a user error, or something you can recover from, then the suggestions above are valid.

Comment: @MikeMB What's stopping me from returning a "proper error code" is that I'm lazy. I only need to return a success/failure status. I could have used a bool, but I wanted to be a bit more helpful with the return value. If I wanted to return a "proper error code", I would have used an enum, and this question would not exist. So everyone, stop suggesting enums and constants. Either help me with being lazy, or don't "help" me at all.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet: The point is that trying to return line numbers and checking for them instead of some arbitrarily chosen, but globally declared error codes results in more, not less work. You still don't have to check those error codes in your production code, but it is far simpler, to declare some global constant (doesn't even have to be an enum, just a plain int) and use it in your function and testcode, than trying to export a certain line number from your function reliably to your testcode.

Comment: That's what I also pointed out in my answer - even if you manage to export the `__LINE__` in variable, you cannot handle that with a single variable (you have **various lines for various error reasons**), so **you would need to export multiple variables** (one for each error reason) anyway, if you want to check for a particular reason. Then you can get the error line from each such particular error reason variable (which is basically what error codes do, they just normally do not contain the error line).

Comment: @axalis I never said I wanted to handle it with a single variable. I wanted as many constants as they are "return __LINE__" statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how I would solve this easily:

```
struct FuncErrorCodes {
    enum Type {
        OK = 0,
        SOMETHING_IS_WRONG,
        SOMETHING_ELSE_IS_WRONG,
        ...
    };
};

typedef FuncErrorCodes::Type FuncErrorCode;

FuncErrorCode func() {
    // stuff
    if (something is wrong) {
        return FuncErrorCodes::SOMETHING_IS_WRONG;
    }
    // more stuff
    if (something else is wrong) {
        return FuncErrorCodes::SOMETHING_ELSE_IS_WRONG;
    }
    ...
    // all good
    return FuncErrorCodes::OK;
}
```

I don't see any reason why I would want to use `__LINE__` for error codes.

In the usual case the return code can still be tested against 0 (or better yet `FuncErrorCodes::OK`) and I'd have no problem testing for the particular error reasons, like for example:

```
FuncErrorCode rc = func();
EXPECT_EQ(FuncErrorCodes::SOMETHING_IS_WRONG, ret);
```

**EDIT**: Note that even if you managed to export the "last line set to the error code" it would not help you in any way, because that would be the exact value the function is returning (so you already know it). For it to actually work, you would need **separate variable for each possible error line**, which will then contain the particular line number (so that it can be checked against the function return code to see if the particular error happened).

I.e. you would need something like:

```
extern int something_wrong_line_number;
extern int something_else_wrong_line_number;

if (something is wrong) {
    something_wrong_line_number = __LINE__; return __LINE__;
}

if (something else is wrong) {
    something_else_wrong_line_number = __LINE__; return __LINE__;
}

// etc. - but it will of course still not work entirely well because the __LINE__ is only assigned if the error actually happens
```

And that is then no different to providing just the simple error codes for each particular error situation as I suggest (and it is much more complicated).